# git-p4 clone is mandatory to run git-p4 sync?

Tags: git, git-p4

I am using git-p4 sync command to get the files from perforce to git repository.

I have been working in git for testing few changes on forked git repository (from original repository). I have buildbot CI build step configured to run `git-p4 sync` command :-

`/home/test-worker/staging-worker/venv3/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/git-p4 sync --use-client-spec --keep-path --branch refs/heads/sv4/main`

I get the issue :-

`No remote p4 branches.  Perhaps you never did "git p4 clone" in here.`

But in original repository, Same build step is working fine where they have not ran any `git-p4 clone` as pre-requisite.

One difference i notice the entry `p4/HEAD -> test/main` in original repo with build command :- `git branch -r` And this entry is created just after running above (git-p4 sync) command. I don't understand why the same entry is not creating in my forked test repository. Please advice.

I try to run `git-p4 clone` on forked test repo (root folder of repo)

`/home/test-worker/staging-worker/venv3/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/git-p4 clone --use-client-spec --keep-path --verbose --branch refs/heads/test/main //sw/pvt/hello`

But it creates new directory named 'hello' inside root folder of forked repo and i could see `p4/HEAD -> test/main` inside the 'test' folder. Basically i don't want to create any new folder. Instead i want to update the forked repo where i have the branch `test/main`.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to call python3 directly. Please add the following alias to etc/gitconfig:

```
[alias]
p4=!python.exe <path to git-p4.py>
```

git p4 clone creates the git repo for the repo in perforce. It should only be used once. After that git p4 sync should be used.

I don't use --use-client-spec. I work directly with the depot so that all files are sync'd

e.g.
git p4 clone --detect-branches "//depot/project1@all"

git p4 sync --detect-branches "//depot/project1@all"